# ActionView::MissingTemplate for create action

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I submit my form I receive a error: Missing template letsgos/create, application/create with `{:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby]}`.

What I am not understanding is why it's looking for /create when the view for create is `from _form.html.erb`. I shouldn't need to make a /create file. Am I missing something here?

**letsgos_controller.rb:**

```
  before_action :signed_in_user, only: [:create, :destroy]

  def create
    @letsgo = current_user.letsgos.build(letsgo_params)
    if @letsgo.save
      flash[:success] = "Date posted!"
      redirect_to root_url
end

  def destroy
    @letsgo.destroy
    redirect_to root_url
  end
```

**users_controller:**

```
def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @letsgos = @user.letsgos.paginate(page: params[:page])
    @letsgo = current_user.letsgos.build if signed_in?'
  end
```

**letsgo.rb:**

```
  belongs_to :user
  default_scope -> { order('created_at DESC') }
  validates :content, presence: true, length: { maximum: 360 }
  validates :tag, presence: true
  validates :user_id, presence: true
end
```

**/users/show.html.erb:**

```
<% if @user.letsgos.any? %>
    Dates (<%= @user.letsgos.count %>)
    <%= render @letsgos %>
    <%= will_paginate @letsgos %>
    <% end %>
```

**/letsgos/_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for(@letsgo) do |f| %>
    <div class="field">
        <%= f.text_area :content, placeholder: "Propose new date..." %>
        </div>
        <%= f.submit "Post", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
        <% end %>
```

**/letsgos/home.html.erb:**

```
<% if signed_in %>
    <% render 'letsgos/form' %>
```

Comment: I don't know if its in your actual code, but as shown, you've got syntax problems on your letsgos_controller.rb (e.g. missing `end` on `def create`).

Comment: I have 2 'end' for the def create. 1 under def destroy. And 2 under the private def letsgo_params. That is all fine.

Comment: Then you should update your code listing in the question, since it only shows 1 `end` for the `def create` (and fix the indentation while you're at it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

inside `letsgoes_controller.rb` you have following create method:

```
  def create
    @letsgo = current_user.letsgos.build(letsgo_params)
    if @letsgo.save
      flash[:success] = "Date posted!"
      redirect_to root_url
    end
  end
```

According to that method, if @letsgo.save return false (because of validation or something else), that code will not be executed, meaning that rails would try to render view file with the same name as the controller action - `create` in this case. So you need to account for the false case of `if`. Something like this would work:

```
  def create
    @letsgo = current_user.letsgos.build(letsgo_params)
    if @letsgo.save
      flash[:success] = "Date posted!"
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      flash[:error] = "Date was not posted!"
      redirect_to root_url
    end
  end
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Now I have to create save action. The silly thing is I had something similar to that where I was trying to use the 'else' and render the homepage. Thank you

Comment: you can render `new` form inside the `else` section (with errors), so you dont have to implement another method - it will reuse `create` action.